# What Windows API do the File.X() and Directory.X() methods use?

Tags: c#, performance, winapi, filesystems

I was comparing the speed of the Windows GUI vs its console, and some of the console commands are actually faster. Deleting a large folder with thousands of files finishes 4 to 10 times faster with a console command, than it does using Shift+Delete in Explorer.

```
rmdir "MyLargeDir" /s /q  ---  delete dir tree quietly
```

I'm assuming the Windows GUI and console use a different API/DLL, maybe the console commands use legacy code which is faster? So I was wondering which Windows API is used by the File.Delete() and other File.X() / Directory.X() functions in .NET. I don't really know the names of the APIs used by the GUI and console, but there *is* a difference, and if the performance boost is so significant I'd rather execute `cmd.exe` rather than calling Directory.Delete().

So my questions:

1. Why does the console `rmdir` execute faster than the Explorer one?
2. What are the different windows APIs used by either? Or is it just the GUI updating that takes time?
3. Do the default .NET classes use the faster API (if any) or should I call `cmd.exe` for max speed?

Comment: Get a copy of ilspy/reflector and you can see exactly what File.Delete() does (it unsurprisingly p./invokes the DeleteFile API)

Comment: Which begs the question, does the DeleteFile API work as fast as the command line `rmdir`? And so on for all Filesystem commands....

Comment: Presumably, benchmark it? I would not compare to the shell however, that's always been slow thanks to the fact it does time calculations, the dumb "Discovering" thing and of course integrates with the recycle-bin (IFileOperation vs DeleteFile() which does not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explorer uses (or at least used to use) [`SHFileOperation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762164.aspx), which I think uses `DeleteFile` internally.

The command prompt utilities use [`DeleteFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363915.aspx) directly.

The speed difference is due to the difference between the two (if you look at the APIs you'll see the first one is much more complicated).

Answer (score 1):

> Why does the console rmdir execute faster than the Explorer one?

We can't know without profiling both applications, but considering that Explorer not only has a GUI that is being kept updated live but in addition to that is designed to load and run third-party code (shell extensions) that may decide to do whatever it wants, it's not surprising that the console is faster.

> What are the different windows APIs used by either?

Of course [there are no different APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364232%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It wouldn't make any sense for more than one API to be provided for such basic file operations.

> Or is it just the GUI updating that takes time?

See first paragraph.

> Do the default .NET classes use the faster API (if any) or should I call cmd.exe for max speed?

They use the same API, but how does .NET come into this? You mentioned a difference in perceived performance between a console window and Explorer. Neither of these is .NET.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but all your points are obvious. Obviously neither the GUI or console are .NET, and I've updated my question to clarify your doubts.

Comment: @Geotarget: If they are obvious then what else do you want to know? The updated question doesn't clarify at all -- you are comparing Explorer with a shell command and then ask about `Directory.Delete`. What's the connection? For all we know just by reading the question, `Directory.Delete` might be a million times faster than the shell.

Comment: Exactly, so the question is for people who *do* know about the internals of such things, not just those who answer "just by reading the question".

Comment: "Of course there are no different APIs" : How can one tell what API the command `rmdir` uses internally, for example? As I said before it could be faster because it uses legacy code thats not available anywhere else. Microsoft might document a single API, but may use multiple different methods internally. And since the console IS faster, I was wondering if the .NET methods are AS fast as the console or SLOWER. Obviously I could profile, and I will, but I asked in case people already know the architecture ...

Comment: @Geotarget: By placing a breakpoint inside kernel32.dll or by using a suitable API monitoring tool, which I invite you to do for yourself. Since you implicitly concede that *you* do *not* know about the internals of such things, IMHO you should try to at least be polite to those who are trying to help you. Also, rmdir *could* be faster because a magic fairy deletes the files with a touch of her wand. Unsubstantiated hypotheses not backed even by an educated guess don't count for much.

Comment: @Geotarget: [Here's](http://chentiangemalc.wordpress.com/2012/02/16/case-of-the-disappearing-pdf/) a blog post that shows how you can very easily confirm that `DeleteFile` is indeed being called when you delete through the shell.

Comment: @Geotarget: I hope you realize that you are presenting hypotheses that do not even hold up to cursory scrutiny: assume that Windows has a hidden file deletion API that is faster than `DeleteFile`. Why on earth would MS *choose* to make `File.Delete` slower by not using that API?

Comment: Maybe the newer API does more, and pays a performance penalty for that "more". Perhaps its updating GUI, or executing an event per directory informing apps that the directory contents have changed, or whatever. Usually newer APIs are slower because they do more stuff, and with this stuff, comes slowness.

Comment: @Geotarget: Does more *what*? Updating GUI is obviously impossible because `DeleteFile` itself cannot even assume that the calling process *has* a GUI, let alone how to update it. Executing an event? What event exactly? Do you see anything in its signature to tell it about some such event? Or do you suggest that there is an undocumented magic event handle somewhere that processes simply tap into (even that would be impossible because kernel events don't work in a way that can support this)? Anyway, there's no sense to go on, I 'm satisfied I made my point.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.changed%28v=vs.110%29.aspx -- This is the event I was referring to. It exists, and it could, in turn update the Explorer GUI or update countless other things in all the apps that subscribe to a "directory changed" event. Lets say I have 2 Explorer windows, deleting a file from one automatically refreshes the other, even if its running in another process or in another app. This is what I mean by "updating GUI". Apps that subscribe to such events could update their own GUIs whenever a directory changes.

Comment: @Geotarget: That is not an event in the usual sense of a [Windows kernel object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682655%28v=vs.85%29.aspx); it's a .NET event that only comes into play if you have properly instantiated an object that exposes it. It's implemented by tapping into [`FindFirstChangeNotification`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364417%28VS.85%29.aspx) and friends, which as you can see must be done explicitly. In any case, an app that deletes files could also choose to sleep for 10 secs each time. That doesn't make `DeleteFile` slow.

Comment: @Jon: *"Assume that Windows has a hidden file deletion API that is faster than `DeleteFile`. Why on earth would MS **choose** to make `File.Delete` slower by not using that API?"* it's called abstraction., and this is in fact the case. [There is a lower-level function called `NtDeleteFile` that can be called from user-mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff556489.aspx), which `DeleteFile` uses.

Comment: @Mehrdad:  abstraction is one thing. Performance is another. NtDeleteFile still has to do all relevant work (e.g. ACL checks), so how exactly is it more performant?

Answer (score -2):

> Why does the console rmdir execute faster than the Explorer one?

In the GUI Windows first estimates the time that is required to perform some action before performing it. This is necessary to show the remaining time in the GUI.

The command line does not show the remaining time and therefore does not have to calculate it!

I heard about an unwanted behavior in Windows copying certain files from a network drive to a local hardrive (or the other way): Windows needed over 30 Minutes for estimating the time required! The time actually required for copying the files was less than one minute. This means: Using the command line you would have been 31 times faster in this case.